# In c++, why does the compiler choose the non-const function when the const would work also?

Tags: c++, constants, overload-resolution, const-reference, function-qualifier

For example, suppose I have a class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::string& Name()
    {
        m_maybe_modified = true;
        return m_name;
    }

    const std::string& Name() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    bool m_maybe_modified;
};
```

And somewhere else in the code, I have something like this:

```
Foo *a;
// Do stuff...
std::string name = a->Name(); // <-- chooses the non-const version
```

Does anyone know why the compiler would choose the non-const version in this case?

This is a somewhat contrived example, but the actual problem we are trying to solve is periodically auto-saving an object if it has changed, and the pointer must be non-const because it might be changed at some point.

Comment: If you want to change some variables in a const function, use the mutual attribute.

Comment: ...and "member variables", I guess.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two answers spring to mind:

1. The non-const version is a closer match.
2. If it called the const overload for the non-const case, then under what circumstances would it *ever* call the non-const overload?

You can get it to use the other overload by casting `a` to a `const Foo *`.

**Edit:** From [C++ Annotations](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus07.html)

> Earlier, in section 2.5.11 the concept
> of function overloading was
> introduced. There it noted that member
> functions may be overloaded merely by
> their const attribute. In those cases,
> the compiler will use the member
> function ***matching most closely the
> const-qualification of the object:***

Answer (score 18):

Because a is not a const pointer. Therefore, a non-const function is a closer match. Here is how you can call the const function:

```
const Foo* b = a;
std::string name = b->Name();
```

If you have both a const and a non-const overload, and want to call the const one on a non-const object, this might be an indication of bad design.

Comment: The full design is hard to express in an example, but there are a few points that could be improved, I'm sure...

We currently do the const pointer method, but it is ugly, and more importantly relies on the programmer to remember to do so.

Comment: How about giving the const overload a different name? Or having both a const overload and a differently named function, one calling the other in-line?

Comment: Just a nit to pick... the pointer isn't const... it's a "pointer to const" in your example.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler does not take into account how you are using the return value in its determination; that's not part of the rules.  It doesn't know if you're doing

```
std::string name = b->Name();
```

or

```
b->Name() = "me";
```

It has to choose the version that works in both cases.

Comment: The question wasn't about the constness or not of the return value, it was about the constness of the object. The -1 wasn't me though.

Comment: I understand the potential problems for the compiler, but I would think that it would be able to make some simple checks such as in the example, where it would be immediately using the return for a copy and then discarding it.

Comment: That would be pretty dangerous, as a change to some other line of code would cause the behavior of that particular call to change as well.  The rules for determining overload resolution are complex enough as it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a "cName" function that is equivalent to "Name() const". This way you can call the const version of the function without casting to a const object first.

This is mostly useful with the new keyword auto in C++0x, which is why they are updating the library to include cbegin(), cend(), crbegin(), crend() to return const_iterator's even if the object is non-const.

What you are doing is probably better done by having a setName() function that allows you to change the name rather than returning a reference to the underlying container and then "maybe" it is modified.

Comment: I realize that it might be better with a setName() function, but again, the example was somewhat contrived.  In actuallity, we have pointers objects containing other objects, and would prefer the const pointers be returned where possible, when strung together as "int c = a->B()->GetC();", etc.